# Create X509V3 Certificate with Customized Extension

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Is it possible to create a X509v3 certificate with customized extension so that in the certificate there will be some customized field and value, such as "Client's Attribute = User_A, iPhone, iOS 7"?

I am currently using BouncyCastle but I am not sure how to add the extension that I want. I am still stuck at the first step to create certificatebuilder as follow:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(4096);
    KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey pub = key.getPublic();
    PrivateKey priv = key.getPrivate();
    X509v3CertificateBuilder v3Bldr = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(issuerBuilder.build(), BigInteger.valueOf(3),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)),
            subjectBuilder.build(), pub);
    ASN1ObjectIdentifier asn1iod =
            new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.3.4");     
    v3Bldr.addExtension(asn1iod,false,b);

    X509CertificateHolder certHldr = v3Bldr.build(new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1WithRSA").setProvider("BC").build(priv));

    X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHldr);;
```

. What should I do next and how to add the customized extension?

EDIT: I have tried to follow the example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412315/creating-custom-x509-v3-extensions-in-java-with-bouncy-castle) but it gave me error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/util/Encodable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Custom X509 v3 Extensions in Java with Bouncy Castle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412315/creating-custom-x509-v3-extensions-in-java-with-bouncy-castle)

Comment: @pedrofb check the update, I forgot to mention it. Not sure what's the problem tbh

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of *both* the bcprov and bcpkix jars.

Answer (score 0):

org/bouncycastle/util/Encodable class appeared in bouncycastle version 1.52 (currently last version is 1.56).
So probably you're using a previous version of bouncycastle.
Well, assuming you already have the bcprov jar in your classpath.